# Recalculate log-likelihood from a R lmer model with one random effect

Tags: r, mixed-model, likelihood

I'm trying to recalculate the REML log-likelihood given by the `logLik` function from a linear mixed model with one random effect. I use the `lmer` function in the `lme4` package and the sleepstudy dataset from the package.

```
model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)
logLik(model, REML=F)
# 'log Lik.' -897.0497 (df=4)
```

My calculation :

```
Z      <- getME(model, 'Z')
sigma2 <- summary(model)$devcomp$cmp[[9]]^2
Xbeta  <- getME(model, 'X') %*% fixef(model)
V      <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(model))$vcov[1] * Z %*% t(Z) + 
                       sigma2 * diag(1, nrow(sleepstudy))
sum(log(dnorm(sleepstudy$Reaction, Xbeta, sqrt(V[1:10, 1:10]))))
# -962.0263
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

### **EDIT**

Using the appropriate function `dmnorm` from package `mnormt` to obtain the density for the multivariate normal distribution, I get :

```
dmnorm(x = sleepstudy$Reaction, mean = as.vector(Xbeta), varcov = V, log = TRUE)
# -897.0553
```

It is not always the right solution.

Comment: One hint for you code: avoid giving names that are already given (here `var`).

Comment: This seems like more of a statistical question than a coding question to me.

Comment: I changed `var` with `sigma2` but the question remains. I still cannot recalculate the log likelihood.

Comment: I don't think the calculation is quite as straightforward as you think. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf for details of the REML criterion (p. 15) ...